# Run bat file with UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, executable, launcher

I'm trying to build UWP app and I'm struggling with an issue:
I have noticed there is now way to launch external executable, but I can open file with its default application using LaunchFile (Like mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_).

Should it work for a .bat file too? Where should i place the .bat file if it is.? Because i tried to give a path to a .bat file i wrote and I got an exception.

Thanks!!

Comment: Which exception?

Comment: @MatanShahar 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x8007007B
  Message=The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at App3.Views.MainPage.<DefaultLaunch>d__8.MoveNext() in ...

Answer (score 2):

Its not going to work.  If you can get some 3rd party application to open and handle bat files by default then maybe, but otherwise nothing the OS handles like cmd or vbscript will run. Not sure what your goal is, but a 3rd party scripting app like Autohotkey does work.

Comment: But I created a bat file that runs in cmd when you just click on it...

@echo off
START "runas /user:administrator" cmd /K "cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\myFolder\ & runit.exe"

Comment: Why are you trying to do that from a UWP app? If you already have `runit.exe` then what does the UWP app do?

Comment: the runit.exe is just a tool that runs the first part of my app... I need to take the results from that runit.exe and parse it.

Comment: UWP is in a sandbox. You're not allowed to launch exe files (either directly or via proxy with a bat file).  Furthermore even if you could launch the file, you would need access to its folder which it appears you don't have given the exception error.  UWP apps can only access appdata folders or the install folder by default.  You can give it access to user library folders in appmanifest.  Any other folder access requires a security token that must be initially obtained at runtime using FilePicker or FolderPicker. [link]https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score -1):

> From .NET 4 there is and [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   classes under the  [System.Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145030(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace which allow you
>   to Win32 applications from C#.

```
public static Task<bool> ExecuteBatchFile(string BatchFilePath, string BatchFileDirectory)
        {
            try
            {
                Task<bool> executeBatchFileTask = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
                {
                    bool hasProcessExited = false;
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        FileName = BatchFilePath,
                        CreateNoWindow = false,
                        UseShellExecute = true,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                        WorkingDirectory = BatchFileDirectory
                    };

                    // Start the process with the info we specified.
                    // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
                    using (System.Diagnostics.Process exeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        while (!exeProcess.HasExited)
                        {
                            //Do nothing  
                        }
                        hasProcessExited = true;
                    }

                    return hasProcessExited;
                });
                return executeBatchFileTask;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And call this method in your code by:

```
bool hasBatchFileExecuted = await ExecuteBatchFile(BatchFilePath, BatchFilePathDirectory);
```

**Create your own batch file like:**

1) Create a text file in notepad and save it as run.bat under save as category and all files.

2) Write the following code to execute a C# program/However you can write your own commands also:

```
csc someRandomCode.cs
pause
```

3) Save and quit.

Comment: So what should i do? Should i need to add that function (ExecuteBatchFile) too? or just call it in my app?

Comment: Just call it in your app passing the batch file path and batch file directory, bool hasBatchFileExecuted = await ExecuteBatchFile(@"C:\Users\Kunal\Desktop\SomeFolder\test.bat", @"C:\Users\Kunal\Desktop\SomeFolder\"); like this, the first parameter is the absolute path of the batch file and the second one is the directory's absolute path. C# will use the Win32 api which will use underneath cmd.exe that will spawn a process that executes your batch file.

Comment: This won't help for a UWP -- The OP wants to elevate to admin. Also doing a busy wait to see if the process has excited is very wasteful -- use the `WaitForExit` method or the `Exited` event.

Comment: I can't call this function.... And if I'm writing this app in my app - it doesn't recognize the ProcessStartInfo and ProcessWindowStyle.

Comment: Add System.Diagonostics namespace

Comment: I did
using System.Diagnostic....
I'm not sure how to import external namespace in UWP.

Comment: @Ben UWP app does not support ProcessStart class. This won't work.